# Use JSONP without wrapping response

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp

My server outputs this JSON when I put the URI in web browser. My client app will get this JSON using JSONP because it accesses the foreign domain.

```
{
"is_execution_successful":true,
"data": "something"
}
```

Is there a way to do a JSONP **without wrapping the response** like this:

```
echo $_GET['json_callback']. '('. json_encode($rtnjsonobj) . ')';
```

I don't have permission to edit the server output. How to get the JSON using AJAX/JQuery?

Reference I read: http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONP has technically nothing to do with JSON. It's simply javascript code.

So if the response is valid JSON, it will not do anything useful when you run it as javascript (JSONP). Especially in this case, the JSON causes a syntax error when executed as javascript.

You can make cross-origin ajax request to the resource, but this is only possible if the server sends this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

*The star can be replaced with your specific origin of course, it doesn't have to be a wildcard*

Comment: I'm still not clear. Do you mean I can't get the response for my app? It's actually a Windows 8 application which gets JSON from PHP site).

Comment: I don't about windows 8 apps, but it would be weird if they were restricted by same origin policy ... have you just tried a direct ajax request?

Comment: I can't get that JSON using direct ajax request. It always returns empty. I think it's not the same domain.

Comment: @Emerald214 Yeah but since you said you are doing this in a win8 app, same origin policy would not make any sense. Can you try this http://lukencode.com/2012/07/09/http-web-services-in-javascript-windows-8-metro-apps/?